# Mime4j: DefaultMessageBuilder fails to parse mbox content

Tags: java, apache, parsing, mbox, mime4j

I've downloaded `mime4j` 0.8.0 snapshot from `subversion` and built it with `maven`.
The relevant jars I generated can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/se5jhtix4h7cvo3/AAAGlUEbTv6Acp8lWHEnMtR5a?dl=0).

Now I try to parse [a toy mbox file](https://github.com/ieugen/mbox-iterator/blob/master/src/test/resources/test-1/mbox.rlug) from `mime4j` test.

I use this [sample code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/james/mime4j/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/james/mime4j/samples/mbox/IterateOverMbox.java). Briefly:

```
final File mbox = new File("c:\\mbox.rlug");
int count = 0;
for (CharBufferWrapper message : MboxIterator.fromFile(mbox).charset(ENCODER.charset()).build()) {
    System.out.println(messageSummary(message.asInputStream(ENCODER.charset())));
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Found " + count + " messages");
```

+

```
private static String messageSummary(InputStream messageBytes) throws IOException, MimeException {
    MessageBuilder builder = new DefaultMessageBuilder();
    Message message = builder.parseMessage(messageBytes);
    return String.format("\nMessage %s \n" +
            "Sent by:\t%s\n" +
            "To:\t%s\n",
            message.getSubject(),
            message.getSender(),
            message.getTo());
}
```

The output is:

> Message null  Sent by:    null To:    null
>
> Message null  Sent by:    null To:    null
>
> Message null  Sent by:    null To:    null
>
> Message null  Sent by:    null To:    null
>
> Message null  Sent by:    null To:    null
>
> Found 5 messages

There are indeed 5 messages, but why are all fields null?

Comment: Could you just print the raw message in the loop, in order to see if it's correctly constructed ? `System.out.println(message);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

`DefaultMessageBuilder` fails to parse mbox files that have windows line separator `\r\n`.
When replacing them with UNIX line separator `\n` the parsing works.

This is a critical issue, since the mbox files downloaded from `Gmail` use `\r\n`.

Comment: You might want to post a change request for the apache james project. My experience with the community there is good.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @zvisofer answer, I found the [guilty piece of code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j-core/0.7/org/apache/james/mime4j/io/BufferedLineReaderInputStream.java/?v=source) in `BufferedLineReaderInputStream`:

```
@Override
public int readLine(final ByteArrayBuffer dst)
        throws MaxLineLimitException, IOException {
    if (dst == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer may not be null");
    }
    if (!readAllowed()) return -1;

    int total = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while (!found) {
        if (!hasBufferedData()) {
            bytesRead = fillBuffer();
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        int i = indexOf((byte)'\n');
        int chunk;
        if (i != -1) {
            found = true;
            chunk = i + 1 - pos();
        } else {
            chunk = length();
        }
        if (chunk > 0) {
            dst.append(buf(), pos(), chunk);
            skip(chunk);
            total += chunk;
        }
        if (this.maxLineLen > 0 && dst.length() >= this.maxLineLen) {
            throw new MaxLineLimitException("Maximum line length limit exceeded");
        }
    }
    if (total == 0 && bytesRead == -1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return total;
    }
}
```

The best thing to do would be to report the bug but here is a fix, a little dirty but it's  working fine

Create the class `org.apache.james.mime4j.io.BufferedLineReaderInputStream` in your project

Replace the method `public int readLine(final ByteArrayBuffer dst)` by this one :

```
@Override
public int readLine(final ByteArrayBuffer dst)
        throws MaxLineLimitException, IOException {
    if (dst == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer may not be null");
    }
    if (!readAllowed()) return -1;

    int total = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while (!found) {
        if (!hasBufferedData()) {
            bytesRead = fillBuffer();
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        int chunk;
        int i = indexOf((byte)'\r');
        if (i != -1) {
            found = true;
            chunk = i + 2 - pos();
        } else {
            i = indexOf((byte)'\n');
            if (i != -1) {
                found = true;
                chunk = i + 1 - pos();
            } else {
                chunk = length();
            }
        }
        if (chunk > 0) {
            dst.append(buf(), pos(), chunk);
            skip(chunk);
            total += chunk;
        }
        if (this.maxLineLen > 0 && dst.length() >= this.maxLineLen) {
            throw new MaxLineLimitException("Maximum line length limit exceeded");
        }
    }
    if (total == 0 && bytesRead == -1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return total;
    }
}
```

Enjoy both unix and dos files :)

Comment: This code causes 5 build tests to fail (one of them is error). I guess that it will fail if you have '\r' not followed by '\n'

Comment: Yes, my fix can be improve I guess, handling the case when \r is alone

Comment: using:
`byte[] microsoftSucks = {(byte)'\r', (byte)'\n'};`
`int i = indexOf(microsoftSucks);`
Fixes 3 tests but two are still failing

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your jar files, the sample code that you pointed to, and the sample mbox file that you pointed to, compiled the sample (with no changes) and ran it against the sample mbox file.

It worked as expected (fields contained the expected data, not nulls).
This was on a Mac with Java 1.6_0_65, and also with 1.8.0_11

Output was as follows:

> $ java -cp .:apache-mime4j-core-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:apache-mime4j-dom-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:apache-mime4j-mbox-iterator-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar IterateOverMbox mbox.rlug.txt
>
> Message Din windows ma pot, din LINUX NU ma pot conecta (la ZAPP) 
>   Sent by:  rlug-bounce@lug.ro To:  [rlug@lug.ro]
>
> Message Re: RH 8.0 boot floppy  Sent by:  rlug-bounce@lug.ro
>   To:   [rlug@lug.ro]
>
> Message Qmail mysql virtualusers +ssl + smtp auth +pop3  Sent
>   by:   rlug-bounce@lug.ro To:  [rlug@lug.ro]
>
> Message Re: Din windows ma pot, din LINUX NU ma pot conecta (la ZAPP) 
>   Sent by:  rlug-bounce@lug.ro To:  [rlug@lug.ro]
>
> Message LSTP problem - solved  Sent by:   rlug-bounce@lug.ro
>   To:   [rlug@lug.ro]
>
> Found 5 messages Done in: 108 milis

Comment: It fails for me on two windows machines. I will try other OS